# Why is it not possible to calculate the amount of combinations for a byte using the Binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to understand the Binomial coefficient.

I found this source which gives clear information: 
https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php

After reading, I was wondering if I could use the Binomial coefficient formula to calculate the amount of possibilities for a byte.

It seems that I can't calculate the amount of combinations by using the Binomial coefficient formula. Because the amount of combinations for bytes should be calculated differently.

For example: 8 bytes gives me 256 combinations. Calculation: `2^8 = 256`.

Q: Why is it not possible to calculate the amount of combinations for a byte using the Binomial coefficient?

Comment: You can... but it is hardly efficient.  You first count how many have no $1$'s as $\binom{8}{0}$.  Add this to the number of bytes with exactly one $1$ bit as $\binom{8}{1}$.  Add this to the number of bytes with exactly two $1$ bits as $\binom{8}{2}$ and so on... You get as a total $\binom{8}{0}+\binom{8}{1}+\binom{8}{2}+\dots+\binom{8}{8}=2^8$ as before.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no wonder you are having trouble, since the page you read does not explain things very well. For example, they say this about the binomial coefficient, which is just simply **wrong**:

> Basically, it shows how many different possible subsets can be made from the larger set.

The number of possible subsets of a set of $n$ elements is $2^n.$ You correctly applied that formula to count the number of possible bytes, in which *any subset* of the eight bits can be set to $1$ and the other bits set to $0.$
The total $2^8$ includes the empty set (which gives you the byte $00000000$), the set of all eight bits (which gives you the byte $11111111$), and subsets with any number of bits between zero and eight.

The binomial coefficient $\binom nr$ counts only the subsets that have *exactly* $r$ elements. You can't count all the bytes using just one binomial coefficient, because the bytes don't all have the same number of $1$s.
You can count all the bytes that have no $1$s (there is just one such byte, and we count it with $\binom 80 = 1$),
you can count the bytes that have eight $1$s (there is just one such byte, and we count it with $\binom 88 = 1$),
you can count the bytes that have one $1$ (there are $\binom 81$ of these),
you can count the bytes that have two $1$s (there are $\binom 82$ of these),
and so forth. But no matter which binomial coefficient you choose, there will be many possible bytes it doesn't count.
The only way to count *all* the bytes with binomial coefficients is to add up several coefficients. (This was shown in a comment.)